# Using BulkUpdateAsync or UpdateRange

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, entity-framework-core, bulkupdate

Until now, I got used async methods everywhere was possible, when the subject was the dbContext. But, for updating entities, I doesn't know an async method and used **UpdateRange** (for entities list).

Now, I found **BulkUpdateAsync**(entities) and I don't see a big difference between these two methods, this accept a IEnumerable list, while UpdateRange which accept a IEnumerable.

Because using **await context.SaveChangesAsync** after each used version, it is necesary to use BulkUpdateAsync?

Its about .Net Core 3 and EF Core 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only methods that actually interact with the database need to be asynchronous.

`UpdateRange` simply tells EF to start tracking the entities; this is done completely synchronously, in memory, and does not commit to the database.

Once you call `await context.SaveChangesAsync` the updates are committed to the database asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, if UpdateRange is propagated only in memory and need SaveChanges, BulkUpdateAsync will save automatically data into db with no needed to use SaveChanges below? Because, if I run both BulkUpdateAsync and SaveChangesAsync, I think this will run syncronously, because SaveChangesAsync need to wait for bulk updates before.

Comment: @AlleXyS I'm not familiar with that method, it looks like it's in a different package to standard EF, but the fact it is async would suggest that it does indeed propagate the updates to the database making `SaveChangesAsync` unnecessary.